# TravisCI : Setup two jobs with different configurations

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am setting up an automated Travis CI CI, and was wondering if it is possible to launch two jobs (same tests) with two different configurations.

My app depends on a `config.json` file, which sets up different DB usages (`json` and `mongo`). My use case is simple: run the tests with a config file using `json` and run the same tests using another config file with `mongo`.

To retrieve config I'm running a `before` script which just gets it from somewhere and saves the file.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try a build matrix: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks! Actually the docs provide a way of doing this [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Multiple-Database-Builds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this is quite simple, depending on the configuration (in this case `env` variables), I run specific scripts that download different configurations for each `env` variable.

```
before_script:
    - sh -c "if [ '$DB' = 'mongo' ]; then sleep 15; fi"
    - sh -c "if [ '$DB' = 'mongo' ]; then wget https://google.com/config.json; fi"
    - sh -c "if [ '$DB' = 'mysql' ]; then wget https://google.com/config2.json; fi"
```

That way when the code runs, you can load different configurations